# Screen Resolution - self-adjusting or a version for small screens and another for larger screens. What is the best option for now and the future? Why?

Tags: web-applications, web, screen, resolution, usability

Screen Resolution - self-adjusting as twitter bootstrap (good user experience) or a version for small screens and another for larger screens (without Media queries, saving resources). What is the best option for now and the future? why?
situations:
- I'm having a website on a mobile device connected to the data projector. I would not want the page reload because of a different resolution.

Save resources vs. user experience for usability engineering for webapps and websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a framework for your web app. display, to make supporting different displays easy.

http://mashable.com/2013/04/26/css-boilerplates-frameworks/